# CodeIgniter + Wamp: Unable to locate the file error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, wamp

I just installed a fresh installation of Wamp server and copied a working CodeIgniter project(not done by me) into it. I have changed the settings in config.php(base_url) and database.php(mysql credentials) and am sure that the database connection is ok.

i can see the login page but when i login, it returns me the "unable to locate the file error", i believe its some settings on the Wamp server i need to do. there is no .htaccess file in the root CI folder, should there be? any suggestions what might went wrong?

[image]

in the controllers folder there is an admin.php file

```
<?php

class Admin extends CI_Controller
{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->lang->load($this->config->item('admin_language'), $this->config->item('admin_language'));
}

private $rules = array(
                    array(
                        'field'   => 'username',
                        'label'   => 'lang:username',
                        'rules'   => 'trim|required',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'field'   => 'password',
                        'label'   => 'lang:password',
                        'rules'   => 'trim|required|min_length[8]',
                    )
                );

function index()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $redirect_to = $this->config->item('base_url') . 'index.php/admin/products/';
    if ($this->auth->logged_in() == FALSE)
    {
        $data['error'] = FALSE;
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->rules);
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');
        //echo "1";die;
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            //echo "if";die;
            $this->load->view('admin/login', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            //echo "el";die;
            $this->auth->login($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password'), $redirect_to, 'index.php/admin/login');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //echo "asdadad";die;
        redirect($redirect_to);
    }
}

function logout()
{
    $this->auth->logout($this->config->item('base_url') . 'index.php/admin');
}
}

?>
```

Comment: check apache's error log

Comment: i checked the apache_error.log file and it just shows startup and shutdown messages

Comment: Can you post the line, which is calling the view?

Comment: You are in views folder. URL needs controllers/login.php file.

Comment: in the controllers folder, there is only an admin.php and index.html

Comment: check document root settings in httpd.conf file

Comment: @icube: then its because you need to have `login` controller inside `admin.php`, which is not present currently ..

Answer (score 0):

Please change you function name index to login.

If you are using function name index then url will we localhost/projectname/index.php/admin

If you change function name to login then this will we work.

Comment: Hi, i don't think its the code's problem because it is working on a linux machine. I believe its some environment settings... but I have tried a few settings and it is still the same

Comment: Try to set route in route.php
like
$route['admin/index'] = "admin/login";